# UICollectionView reload data doesn't work in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I migrated my ios app code to Swift 4 and reload data method in my collection views doesn't work. I searched and try a lot of things but no one worked. It was working perfectly for more than a month in Swift 3, so I don't know what is happening.

This code is for one of the cases:

```
private func setLevelLessons(){
        let operationsDB = DBOperations()
        self.indexInformation = operationsDB.getIndex(forLevel: self.currentLevel)
        self.numLessons = (self.indexInformation?.count)!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.lessonsCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

I call this function when a button is clicked. When is clicked I get data from database and reload collection view. I checked if data is correct so that's not the problem.

I printed items when next method is called, and is called in the first and second click (second not necessary in the button, no matter where in the screen)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

What could be happening?

Comment: Check your `numOfRowAtIndexPath` return count

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani That value is correct, I get it from `numLessons` variable.

Comment: I encountered a similar effect and for me worked _[collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]_ before _[collectionView reloadData]_. In my case the collectionview-viewcontroller (obj-c) is a child-viewcontroller of a swift-viewcontroller.

Comment: @Apoc Doesn't work for me. Thank you for your answer. In some cases is working with `collectionView.reloadSections([i])` but is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had this problem when update to Swift4 and Xcode 9.0, but today I upgrade Xcode to 9.0.1 version (released yesterday) and `collectionView.reloadData()` is working again. So, if you have this problem ensure you have last Xcode version or wait until next version is released.

Answer (score 0):

It is a temporary solution in swift4 (Xcode 9).

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
  let indexPaths = [Int](0..<numberOfItems).map{ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
  collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
}
```